# Android Compile Dependencies - Gradle Build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

My question is a simple one which I'm not sure how to tackle.

When compiling libraries in gradle, I use the code shown below:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.+'
}
```

This gives me the what I want and I have no issues whatsoever. I'm guessing the code above makes sure that the latest version of each dependency is compiled when the app is built (hence the "+" sign at the end of each statement). However, I've seen in many places online where the same lines of code are as shown below without the "+" sign:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

There is no discernible difference and both work fine the same. But as a developer with intentions to have long term support for the app, which should I use? With or without the appended "+" sign. **What are the possible benefits or issues from using one over the other?** Any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should use with "+". You don't have to worry about updates. If the updated version of library is available, Android Studio will automatically compile the updated library. However, if the updated library contains bugs, you may have to change the older version number.

Comment: if you turn on lints it says `Avoid using + in version numbers, can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the **+**, Android Studio can update the dependencies that you are using in your project.

It can be a problem because you will not be able to know which version was included in a particolar version of the app.

**It is very important to have reproducible build results.**

Also there are some differences using:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

In the first case you will update only the minor changes (bug fixes in most of cases). In the second case you will update maior relases. For example there are a lot of change from 22.0.0 and 22.2.0.
The final case is the most dangerous. Don't use it in any case.

Comment: Hi Grabriele, thanks for the response. Your explanation is very clear. Before I finalise this question, do you know if there is a way for the developer to check with Google which is the latest version of that specific dependency? Is there a Google web address somewhere (repository?). Somewhere where I can check which is the latest version for appcompat dependency? Just in case I decide to go with static and want to know if there is a new release for that specific dependency.

Comment: About support libraries, Android Studio should advice you when you are using a old dependencies. In any case, you can check here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

For all other libraries you can check here:
http://search.maven.org/

Answer (score 0):

if you use + so it check every time for update and it would be broken build 
when on static it provide dependancy for particular version

Answer (score 0):

Actually, +'s mean that you let Android Studio to use future versions of the library as they are updated. As opposed to that, not adding a + means that it will use only the specific version mentioned.
Use those +'s based on varying situations. Things like appcompat are quite stable, so you may not want to add +'s. 
Things like the newly released android design library are well, new, unstable and buggy and you would want to receive bugfixes and updates. Add the +'s in that case.